# Find Center of Rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas

How do you find the center coordinates of a Rectangle drawn in the canvas? The only items I have is the left, right, bottom, and top values.

```
Rect newRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(newRect, paint);
```

Comment: How much thought did you put into this question?

Comment: @Edwin - I am just trying to put out the questions that I had while learning how to develop more on the canvas (no matter how simple). Someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) methods [centerX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#centerX%28%29) and [centerY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#centerY%28%29)

```
Rect newRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(newRect, paint);
int xCenter = newRect.centerX();
int yCenter = newRect.centerY();
```

Or if you need a float value for better precision, use [exactCenterX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#exactCenterX%28%29) and [exactCenterY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#exactCenterY%28%29)

```
float xCenter = newRect.exactCenterX();
float yCenter = newRect.exactCenterY();
```

Comment: This was more along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

center = 0.5(left+right), 0.5(bottom+top)